# Methods for multiple file upload in android

Tags: android, file-upload

I have scenario where i need to transfer one or more file depending on situation over the network. The size of the files will be between 700KB and 900KB. After upload completes the server will respond with one number, irrespective of the number of files uploaded.
I have been trying to upload it with ksoap2 library after converting it to Base64, but it failed. It would fail when size of my soap header xml size goes around some where 1048000 or so chars.

Then i decided to change my way of upload and am looking to use either HttpURLConnection or http client.
I cannot decide on which one will be efficient for my scenario.

Thanks

Here is the code

code:

```
            InputStream is = getResources()
                    .openRawResource(R.raw.file_name);

            int size = 0;
            // Read the entire resource into a local byte buffer.
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            try {

                while ((size = is.read(buffer, 0, 1024)) >= 0) {
                    baos.write(buffer, 0, size);
                }

                is.close();
                buffer = baos.toByteArray();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            base64string = new String(Base64.encode(buffer, Base64.DEFAULT));
```

error

```
org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: unexpected type (position:END_DOCUMENT null@1:1 in java.io.InputStreamReader@4101ce48)  
at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.nextTag(KXmlParser.java:2035)
at org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope.parse(SoapEnvelope.java:126)
at org.ksoap2.transport.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:63)
at org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE.call(HttpTransportSE.java:100)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know what kind of server you would like to use. 
Your issue of that the files stops while upload might be in your server settings. in your php config for example you can define maximum uploaded file sizes etc. 
here a php example:

```
public void uploadFile(){


try {
FileInputStream fis =this.openFileInput(NAME_OF_FILE);
HttpFileUploader htfu = new HttpFileUploader("http://11.0.6.23/test2.php","noparamshere", NAME_OF_FILE);
htfu.doStart(fis);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Read more: http://getablogger.blogspot.com/2008/01/android-how-to-post-file-to-php-server.html#ixzz27YPjwX8B

EDIT: You could also try to make your soap transfer more efficient by implementing MTOM:

Check out MTOM, a W3C standard designed to transfer binary files through SOAP.

From Wikipedia:

```
    MTOM provides a way to send the binary data in its original binary form, 
    avoiding any increase in size due to encoding it in text.
```

Related resources:

SOAP Message Transmission Optimization Mechanism http://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-mtom/

Message Transmission Optimization Mechanism (Wikipedia) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MTOM

Comment: I can upload small files through soap, but the issu is with bigger files. When i upload bigger files say 850KB through soap it fails. The server guy says at that time noting comes from my app.

Comment: so you have actually no access to the server? do you know what the server is configured as? it sounds like a server problem. nevertheless you could try my suggestion.

Comment: It is a PHP server. I tried to pass request through webend and it works fine even for a 1 MB file. I cannot go with you suggested method as the server currently uses SOAP. I have to pass authentication headers and all stuff before actual data. But if all fails i can suggest my manager to change the server code that can help achieve the purpose.

Comment: are you getting any errors in the logs? might be a problem in your soap_action or in your methods. can you post some code?

Comment: I have added code, i pass the created Base64String as xml to my server. But as I said i can upload small files not bigger one so there cannot be issue with my methods or soap_actions

Comment: See my edit above for using MTOM to send your data using binary form through soap. that will also save your data transmission by ~30% and therefore makes your app working faster.

Comment: hey I have got the implementation done like the way described in the link you provided: http://getablogger.blogspot.com/2008/01/android-how-to-post-file-to-php-server.html#ixzz27YPjwX8B. I am concerned is how to implement multiple file uploads here.

Comment: good. so you are doing it the php way now. you should basically just need to create a second or more FileInputStream and HttpFileUploader like this: FileInputStream fis2 =this.openFileInput(NAME_OF_FILE);
HttpFileUploader htfu2 = ...